# I can connect to a OPC DA Server, but if I try read Items I get always "Opc.ResultIDException: E_FAIL IOPCItemMgt.AddItems" What could be the problem?

Tags: c#, opc

I can connect to an OPC DA Server, that is not in the same domain as my PC,  but if I try to read Items I get always the exception

> Opc.ResultIDException: E_FAIL IOPCItemMgt.AddItems" at OpcCom.Da.Subscription.AddItems(Item[] items).

For testing if anything is wrong with my PC DCOM settings, I tried "OPC DA Expert Client" to connect to the same machine. With OPC Expert OPC DA Client, everything works fine. I can connect and also read the tags. Here is my code: ( I have marked the place where I get the exception)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a server object and connect to the TwinCATOpcServer            
        
        OpcCom.Factory fact = new OpcCom.Factory();                       

        server = new Opc.Da.Server(new OpcCom.Factory(), new Opc.URL(Opc.UrlScheme.DA + OPC_server_ip + OPC_id));

        try
        {
            //server.Connect(url, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));
            server.Connect();
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(OPC_Log))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("OPC Connection OKKK !!!: " + "  " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception except)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(OPC_Log))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("OPC Connection Error: " + except + "  " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now));
            }
        }


        // Create a group
        Opc.Da.Subscription group;
        Opc.Da.SubscriptionState groupState = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
        groupState.Name = "Group";
        groupState.Active = false;
        group = (Opc.Da.Subscription)server.CreateSubscription(groupState);

        // add items to the group
        Opc.Da.Item[] items = new Opc.Da.Item[3];
        items[0] = new Opc.Da.Item();

        items[0].ItemName = "!I4,MTX,Plc.PVL,Application.GLOBALE_VARIABLEN.AxesPos[0]";

        items[1] = new Opc.Da.Item();

        items[1].ItemName = "!I4,MTX,Plc.PVL,Application.GLOBALE_VARIABLEN.AxesPos[1]";

        items[2] = new Opc.Da.Item();

        items[2].ItemName = "!I4,MTX,Plc.PVL,Application.GLOBALE_VARIABLEN.AxesPos[2]";

        items = group.AddItems(items);


 // At this point I get the exception     ************************************************************
 //***********************************************************************************************
        
        Opc.IRequest req;
        

        // and now read the items again
        group.Read(group.Items, 123, new Opc.Da.ReadCompleteEventHandler(ReadCompleteCallback), out req);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void WriteCompleteCallback(object clientHandle, Opc.IdentifiedResult[] results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write completed");
        foreach (Opc.IdentifiedResult writeResult in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0} write result: {1}", writeResult.ItemName, writeResult.ResultID);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void ReadCompleteCallback(object clientHandle, Opc.Da.ItemValueResult[] results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Read completed");
        foreach (Opc.Da.ItemValueResult readResult in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\tval:{1}", readResult.ItemName, readResult.Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be missing ClientHandle in your items